# is there a way to reorder the recordtype picklist available in report builder

Tags: reporting, configuration

I find that when I want to select from the list of record types in the report builder, for lets say Opportunitity record types, the list presented is not sorted alphabetically but instead by order of creation it seems, is there a way to reorder this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to reorder record types at all (e.g. when creating new records). I'd suggest posting an idea on the [IdeaExchange](http://ideas.salesforce.com/). As a workaround, you could create new record types in the desired order, then delete the old ones (using the replace feature). That might be problematic for highly detailed configurations.